# Is OLAP4J dead and is there a replacement equivalent?

Tags: java, xmla, olap4j

Is OLAP4J (Java library for connecting to XMLA services) dead? The things that suggest it is are:

- The [web site](http://www.olap4j.org) hasn't been updated since 2013.
- The [last message](https://sourceforge.net/p/olap4j/mailman/olap4j-devel/) on the dev mailling list was in May 2016.
- The last available release build was [1.2.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.olap4j/olap4j), in 2016. There are more recent [release tags](https://github.com/olap4j/olap4j/releases), but the build artefacts haven't been uploaded to any Maven repository.

If it is dead, then is there a suitable replacement?

Comment: Judging by what you have described, it seems pretty much dead. It may be the case that the library is still alive, but with similar or different name.

Comment: People voting to close, feel free to add a comment elaborating why you think this question is "off-topic"...

Comment: @jon-hanson It is off-topic to ask for a library recommandation.

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: @Yassin The main part of the question is to establish if olap4j is dead. This type of question occurs elsewhere on StackOverflow and they're not closed.

Comment: @jon-hanson I'm sorry I'm just answering your question and find it legitimate in a way but don't think it is the place to ask it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am the original author of olap4j, and also own the [www.olap4j.org](http://www.olap4j.org) domain. Development has certainly been slow recently, but I wouldn't say the project is dead. If people have pull requests to contribute, then I will be happy to commit them to the project and make new releases.

I don't know of any alternatives to olap4j. The idea that you can connect to any XML/A-compliant OLAP engine via Java, get metadata in the same way that you would from a JDBC data source, and that your code depends only on the API, not a particular driver implementation, is still a good one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We're currently using 1.2.0 and are seeing some odd behaviour, so we wanted to upgrade to a more recent version. However there doesn't seem to be builds for 1.3.0, or for any other newer version.